# Magento 2.1.9 Composer error

Tags: magento2, composer, magento-2.1.9, git

I'm getting the following error using Magento 2.1.9:

```
"Package magento/composer's source key should be specified as {"type": ..., "url": ..., "reference": ...},
{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/magento\/composer.git","reference":null} given.";i:1;s:7856:
```

I think i mucked up my composer file trying to install  a solution for multiple warehouse inventory.

My composer file looks like this:

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.0.13",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.9",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "eadesignro/module-warehouses": "1.0.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "2.3.*",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "sample-module-news": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:EaDesgin/magento2-warehouses"
    },
    "magento2-warehouses": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@github.com:EaDesgin/magento2-warehouses"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

}

Because of this I wasn't able to install new extensions or anything. Thanks for you help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you have updated from 2.0.13 to 2.1.9 maybe you have to apply a patch described here
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_21-upgrade.html

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. Unless i need to be running some command after I overwrote the files. 

If not, is there other files that could have been messed with that I could possibly revert back?

Answer (score 0):

Your `composer.lock` file seems to be broken. Can you restore it from version control or backup?

If not, you still have the option to delete it and run a fresh `composer install`. You might end up with different installed versions of the dependencies than before, but at least Magento itself and the installed extension is specified by exact version in `composer.json`

Comment: Hey, sorry this took me so long to reply. I don't have a version that seems to work. When i try `composer install `, I still get the same error posted at the beginning. Is there some other way i should go about reinstalling composer? As it stands I can't even access the Magento admin panel as it gives me the same error code. 

Your help is so appreciated and sorry for any novice-esque questions.

Answer (score 0):

delete composer.lock and vendor folder and then try composer install