# Source Key should be specified

Tags: magento2, php, composer

We are in the process of moving our Magento site to a new hosting platform. After moving all of the files and making some changes to the template XML, the frontend of the site is now working as expected.

However, when logging into the backend, we receive the following error:

```
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Package craftyclicks/module-ukpostcodelookup's source key should be specified as {"type": ..., "url": ..., "reference": ...},
{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/craftyclicks\/magento2-ukpostcodelookup.git","reference":null} given.
```

I have installed the MDVA-532 patch as suggested [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202588/magento-2-1-9-composer-error), but to no avail. What's strange is that the site in its current form is working on another server running EasyApachePHP4. Can anyone suggest a fix?

For reference, here's a copy of the relevant area from our `composer.lock` file:

```
{
    "name": "craftyclicks/module-ukpostcodelookup",
    "version": "1.0.11",
    "source": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/craftyclicks/magento2-ukpostcodelookup.git",
        "reference": ""
    },
    "dist": {
        "type": "zip",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/craftyclicks/magento2-ukpostcodelookup/zipball/",
        "reference": "",
        "shasum": "18da5c12868d070721bc3113a8fbf0f32ac21358"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0 || ~5.6.0 || ^7.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Craftyclicks\\Ukpostcodelookup\\": ""
        }
    },
    "license": [
        "MIT"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Gabor Peter Suranyi",
            "homepage": "https://craftyclicks.co.uk/",
            "role": "Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Gregory Toth",
            "homepage": "https://craftyclicks.co.uk/",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "description": "Apply postcode lookup to Magento 2."
},
```